Book series about humanity having to go through multiple layers/worlds
I'm looking for a book series I read years ago and can't remember the name of.
It's about humanity having to go through multiple layers/worlds. I remember the main character goes back to the start of the event and buys a tome with abilities that summon various types of words and was called something like 'gilded steel' or something like that. And each layer is like its own world with its own inhabitants, monsters and dangers.

In roughly which year/s did you read these books? And just to be clear, what exactly was called gilded steel? The tome?

I would say four plus years and yes the the tome was called something like gilded steel. And the first ability let him summon different swords to use

This thing? https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_book#:~:text=one.%5B28%5D-,Tome%20of%20Morning,-This%20holy%20book / https://www.worldanvil.com/w/not-forgotten-realms-palant/a/the-tome-of-the-morning-article

No that's not it
